# Is there a way to search user/screen names in tweepy (or any other API package) using partial names like using contains or %?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I am able to lookup users using the below command...

```
Search = 'Amazon'
users = api.search_users(q = Search)
results = []
for user in users:
  name = user.name
  screen_name= user.screen_name
  results.append([name, screen_name])
results = pd.DataFrame(results)
results.columns = ['name', 'screen_name']
results
```

...and I was wonder if there was a way to use some form of contains/islike/% lookup when I only know part of the name. So for instance. If I was looking for Amazon, could I do something where I state theat

`api.search_users(q is like 'Amaz%')`

Furthermore, I believe that the search_users function is looking up by the screen name. Is there a function that looks it up by the user name instead?

Answer (score 2):

There is no Twitter API function for this (wildcard or contains lookup, or user name instead of screen name), so there is no way for Tweepy or other libraries to offer the functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would be a nice feature add for very specific use cases.

Answer (score 0):

We are as persian and other languages users cant use it cuz we just cant show our exact name inside an english alphabet user_id and we allways use and search people with their unicode display names.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32168699)